# Auto clicking Google Pay button in Woocommerce payments (Stripe) after 5 seconds

Tags: iframe, stripe-payments, click, google-pay

H1,
I have a Woocommerce site, with woocommerce-payments installed and Google-pay button (Stripe) active.
I want to show the payment popup from google pay, after a set time interval, both on phone (android/iOS) and desktop. So, basically, what i need is to be able to programmatically click the pay button.

Its a more complex setup, so don't wonder why precisely i need such a thing. I don't need the payment form to be auto submitted, all i need is for it to show up so the customer can proceed with the payment without having to click on the "Pay with google" button.

The button is inside an iframe , this is the code for the google pay button that's loading the frame (i removed style and other details from the stripe url):

```
<div id="wcpay-payment-request-wrapper" style="...">
    <div id="wcpay-payment-request-button" class="StripeElement">
        <div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="...">
            <iframe name="__privateStripeFrame51244" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"
                role="presentation" allow="payment *" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-payment-request-..."
                title="Secure payment button frame" style="..."></iframe>
            <input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false"
                maxlength="1" style="...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside the iframe from Stripe, here is the relevant code, with styles removed to keep it short

```
<form class="ElementsApp is-empty" dir="ltr">
    <input tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true" class="StripeField--fake" disabled="" autocomplete="fake" style="...">
    <button id="primary" class="GooglePayButton GooglePayButton--buy GooglePayButton--lightOutline"
        aria-label="Buy with Google Pay" role="button" type="submit" style="..">
        <div class="GooglePayButton-logo"
            style="background-image: url(&quot;https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/img/en-7137d3c501571de27cab87f116edd341.svg&quot;);">
        </div>
    </button><input tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true" class="StripeField--fake" disabled="" autocomplete="fake"
        style="...">
    <button tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" type="submit" style="..."></button>
</form>
```

I tried clicking the google-pay button programmatically by js with the following code:

```
<script>
(function () {
    function triggerfrmbtn(){
        var sFrame = document.getElementsByClassName("__PrivateStripeElement")[0];
        let sFrameButton = sFrame.contents().find('#primary');
        sFrameButton.trigger("click");
    }
    setTimeout(triggerfrmbtn,7000);
 })();
</script>
```

But of course something is not right. I have two issues i think..

1. how do i access the button inside an iframe **ON AN OTHER DOMAIN**
2. how do i click it on both desktop and mobile

I am afraid its impossible, but i thought to ask maybe someone smarter knows a solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All payment method calls need to be called within a user gesture. There mustn't be any delay between the user gesture action (button click) and the call to that method. This is something to align with the user UI expectation/experience of 'I click, then a visual thing happens', also in order to protect the user from being shown the pay button without his explicit request. That could lead to security vulnerability.

Comment: I know how things should be, i asked how to circumvent the way they should be..

Comment: you can't for this case.

Comment: Not even by using a scripted clicker that somehow autoruns? Must be a way for every impossible situation somehow

Comment: AFAIK, no. You'll receive `function must be called during a user gesture` error